# Treat two variables equally in a switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, var, equivalent

I have two variables and i want to run the through the same switch statement with the same results

```
var n1 = first_number;
var n2 = second_number;

switch(for n1 and n2 at the same time){
case "if n1 or n2 depending on which is being tested = something":
do something to the one of n1 or n2 that matches the case
};
```

sorry for the bad explanations, i tried but i just can't explain it better

Comment: Use `if` and `else if`.

Comment: Switch statements can only work properly with on variable. It's used to avoid having multiple `if` nested. If you need to compare more than one variable you will need `if` statements as Florent suggests.

Comment: ok but is it any different if i'm trying to put two vars through the same cases, i was thinking something on the lines of this = value;

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `if` seems to be more appropriate for what you are trying to do.

That being said, there is a way to "trick" `switch` into doing what your asking and it can be useful in **very rare** occasions. Using the logic that you described, you would do this:

```
var n1 = first_number;
var n2 = second_number;

switch(true) {
    case (n1 === something || n2 === something) :
        . . . do stuff . . .
};
```

In those rare cases, the fallthrough of the `case` statements can make this approach useful, but it can also make setting it up correctly even trickier.

### Again, I would strongly recommend using an `if` statement instead.

Comment: This looks very interesting, any suggestions on where one would use this?

Comment: @AsoneTuhid - honestly, I'm having trouble coming up with a good example where this use of `switch(true)` would be preferred to if/else.   LOL   An example of where you COULD use it would be on something like an ordering system where you get a discount if you order a minimum of any item: `case (orderDetails.totalApples >= 50  ||  orderDetails.totalOranges >= 25) : **APPLY DISCOUNT**`  But, again, this could easily be handled with if/else, tweaks to the `orderDetials`  data structure, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var n1 = 'first_number';
var n2 = 'second_number';

if (n1 && n2) {
    //Do something with n1 and n2
} else if (n1 && !n2) {
    //Do something with n1    
} else if (!n1 && n2) {
    //Do something with n2
} else {
    //Default   
}
```

if you like it more complicated

```
var n1 = 'first_number';
var n2 = 'second_number';
var n = [n1, n2];

switch (n.join(';')) {
    case "first_number;second_number":
        //Do something
        break;
    case "first_number":
        //Do something
        break;
    case "second_number":
        //Do something
        break;
    default:
        console.log('default');
        break;
}
```

Comment: son o way with switch? or any other method?
just trying to condense my code

Comment: There is very unconventional way. i've edited my answer

Comment: I just thought of it myself, just make a function with that switch and call it twice, a lot less code and it can be done with many more variables